# Error 'aticonfig: No supported adapters detected' while installing AMD Catalyst

Tags: drivers, xorg, ati, radeon

I have Thinkpad E520 with two graphic cards: Intel and ATI Radeon 6630M.

I am using Ubuntu 10.4 and laptop's internal display runs only on 1024x.

I cannot use external displays (they are not recognized). I am trying to fix this by switching from  Intel card to ATI one. To this end, I downloaded AMD catalyst 12.1 Linux drivers, created package, and installed them. This driver supports my card.

However, when I run `aticonfig` I get a message that my card is not found.

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [AMD wiki site](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware), supported hardware section your card is not supported by the drivers.

You can try to use the drivers in your card (not sure on how that will work) by getting a sample `xorg.conf` file and placing it in your `/etc/X11/` folder.

The `xorg.conf` file has many options and can vary from system to system, the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI_Catalyst) page for ATI Catalyst contains some information about them, have a look.

Comment: Thank you for response. While the ATI drivers are not supported under Ubuntu 11 it works fine.